# Google Cloud Logging from Java, How can I solve it and why occurs?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, logging, keycloak, google-cloud-logging

I want to add Java-Logging from Google Cloud Logging and I have the follow error

```
2023-10-25 12:22:54,385 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) Uncaught server error: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.logging.v2.LogBucket tried to access method 'com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList.emptyList()' (com.google.logging.v2.LogBucket and com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList are in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader @2b9627bc)
    at com.google.logging.v2.LogBucket.<init>(LogBucket.java:400)
    at com.google.logging.v2.LogBucket.<clinit>(LogBucket.java:3050)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.stub.GrpcConfigServiceV2Stub.<clinit>(GrpcConfigServiceV2Stub.java:111)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.stub.ConfigServiceV2StubSettings.createStub(ConfigServiceV2StubSettings.java:675)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.ConfigClient.<init>(ConfigClient.java:212)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.ConfigClient.create(ConfigClient.java:195)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.GrpcLoggingRpc.<init>(GrpcLoggingRpc.java:192)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:66)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:60)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:564)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions.getLoggingRpcV2(LoggingOptions.java:153)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.<init>(LoggingImpl.java:130)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:46)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:544)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.isLocal(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:271)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.createWelcomePage(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:189)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.getWelcomePage(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:71)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:430)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:408)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$0(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2023-10-25 12:22:54,646 SEVERE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper] (executor-thread-0) *~*~*~ Channel ManagedChannelImpl{logId=1, target=logging.googleapis.com:443} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
    Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.: java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper$ManagedChannelReference.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:93)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:53)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:44)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:631)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:297)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:391)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:107)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:85)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:237)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:231)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:236)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:143)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.GrpcLoggingRpc.<init>(GrpcLoggingRpc.java:150)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:66)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:60)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:564)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions.getLoggingRpcV2(LoggingOptions.java:153)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.<init>(LoggingImpl.java:130)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:46)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:544)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.isLocal(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:271)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.createWelcomePage(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:189)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.getWelcomePage(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:71)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:430)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:408)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$0(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2023-10-25 12:22:54,648 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.logging.v2.stub.GrpcConfigServiceV2Stub
    at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.stub.ConfigServiceV2StubSettings.createStub(ConfigServiceV2StubSettings.java:675)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.ConfigClient.<init>(ConfigClient.java:212)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.v2.ConfigClient.create(ConfigClient.java:195)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.GrpcLoggingRpc.<init>(GrpcLoggingRpc.java:192)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:66)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:60)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:564)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions.getLoggingRpcV2(LoggingOptions.java:153)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.<init>(LoggingImpl.java:130)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:46)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:544)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.isLocal(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:271)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.createWelcomePage(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:189)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.getWelcomePage(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:71)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:430)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:408)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$0(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Generate Service Account Key (JSON)
2. Add Environment variable like this: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/my/key.json`
3. Download Open source cloud from `Keycloak 21.0.2`
4. Open directory `quarkus/runtime`
5. Add dependency to `pom.xml`

   ```xml
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.11</version>
        </dependency>
   ```
6. Try to write logs from the method `isLocal()` on the class `src/main/java/org/keycloak/quarkus/runtime/services/resources/QuarkusWelcomeResource.java`

   ```java
   private boolean isLocal() {
        try {
            ClientConnection clientConnection = session.getContext().getConnection();
            InetAddress remoteInetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(clientConnection.getRemoteAddr());
            InetAddress localInetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(clientConnection.getLocalAddr());
            HttpRequest request = session.getContext().getHttpRequest();
            HttpHeaders headers = request.getHttpHeaders();
            String xForwardedFor = headers.getHeaderString("X-Forwarded-For");
            logger.debugf("Checking WelcomePage. Remote address: %s, Local address: %s, X-Forwarded-For header: %s",
                    remoteInetAddress.toString(), localInetAddress.toString(), xForwardedFor);
            LoggingOptions options = LoggingOptions.getDefaultInstance();
            try (Logging logging = options.getService()) {
                LogEntry firstEntry = LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of(String.format(
                        "Checking WelcomePage. Remote address: %s, Local address: %s, X-Forwarded-For header: %s",
                        remoteInetAddress.toString(), localInetAddress.toString(), xForwardedFor)))
                        .setLogName("test-mrp4sten-log")
                        .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global")
                                .addLabel("project_id", options.getProjectId())
                                .build())
                        .build();
                logging.write(Collections.singleton(firstEntry));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Access through AJP protocol (loadbalancer) may cause that remoteAddress is
            // "127.0.0.1".
            // So consider that welcome page accessed locally just if it was accessed really
            // through "localhost" URL and without loadbalancer (x-forwarded-for header is
            // empty).
            return isLocalAddress(remoteInetAddress) && isLocalAddress(localInetAddress) && xForwardedFor == null;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
   ```
7. Compile project on directory `keycloak/quarkus` using  `mvn clean install -DskipTests`
8. Uncompress file `keycloak/quarkus/dist/target/keycloak-21.0.2.tar.gz`
9. Execute `keycloak-21.0.2/bin/kc.sh start-dev`